# Загрузка со скрытой прямой ссылкой

Tags: url, php

Мне нужно сделать скачивание файла на PHP, но так, чтобы пользователь не знал, где находится конечный файл.

Файл платный. Пользователь его покупает и получает уникальную ссылку для его скачивания.

Несколько вопросов.

1. Где на сервере обычно хранят файлы, чтобы их не достать "случайно", так сказать.
2. Как будет выглядеть ссылка (что там кодировать)
3. Собственно как качать файл пользователю (если можно, пример PHP кода)
4. Есть ли простой скрипт для изучения с таким функционалом? Ну или какой-нибудь класс PHP?
5. Для себя... Что писать в Google, от чего плясать?

Сам я просто не знаком с принципом работы такой штуки. Не знаю, с чего начинать и как делать.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) положите .htaccess в папку (любую, где будут файлы)  c записью : Deny all 
2) отдавайте все файлы через некий скрипт php 
3) пишите в базу какой-нибудь уникальный хеш для скачки (например md5(time().[id-файла])) 
4) после того как отдали по хешу файл - удаляйте с базы данный хеш или делайте его [уже скачан]

Comment: А как скриптом заставить файл скачиваться?

Comment: На счет хэша - он будет доступен только для одного пользователя. Никто другой по нему скачать файл не сможет, кроме авторизованного покупателя

Comment: И да. Чем отличается Deny all от Deny From all ?

Comment: [`readfile($filename)`][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php

Comment: 1)   
   `header('Content-type: application/txt');`   //Тип    
   `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ИМЯ.txt"');`   //имя     
   `echo $file;`   //файл   

   
2) Deny From all  - правильно   
3) Если хеш сгенерировать достаточно случайный и выдавать только авторизированному пользователю(можно писать в базу связку пользователь -- хеш) - то хеш будет доступен только данному юзверю

Comment: это общая схема, прикрутить можно достаточно всего, смотря от реализации и требований